# Parse/parse.h file not found after adding prime31 plugin in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, parse-platform, prime31

Before I add Prime31 social networking plugin to my Unity application, all is well when using Parse.

When I add Prime31 SocialNetworking plugin and build to Xcode I start getting on the parse import line.

```
#import <Parse/Parse.h> 'Parse/Parse.h' file not found.
```

Ideas?

Comment: that could be that the plugins dont work together, prime31 has a programming guideline that a plugin has to do for their plugins to be compatible with others, i know that FacebookUnity SDK will not work with prime31 plugins, that may not even be the case, could be though

Answer (score 0):

The answer in our case was that yes, the plugin was conflicting. Parse has you include the frameworks Parse.framework and Bolts.framework. It appears that Bolts.framework, or parts of it, are already included in the prime31 plugin.

**We removed the Bolts.framework added for/by Parse and all is well again.**